# Calling a Coroutine from UI button gets unpredictable behavior Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton, coroutine

**SOLVED: Updated Unity to version 2017.2**

[image: UI button On Click manager]

When adding more than 1 task to the execution list of UI button On Click() manager, the execution of those tasks gets unpredictable behavior. My countdown script counts twice as fast when there is more than one task added to that list (se the attached image). When I remove one task, the code runs as it should (prints the countdown to the screen every second 5..4..3..2..1 etc). Unity Bug?

```
public IEnumerator Countdown()
{
    while (timeLeft > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        countText.text = timeLeft.ToString("f0");
        timeLeft--;          
    }
}

public void StartCountDown()
{
    StartCoroutine("Countdown");
}
```

Comment: so is the Co-routine being run twice simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, it is. And accordingly when I add one more task (3 tasks totally) to the On Click() list it runs 3 times and so on. Why does it behave like this?

Answer (score 2):

Each time the coroutine function is called, `timeLeft` variable is being modified. If you call that coroutine function again while the first one is running then multiple coroutine functions will be modifying the `timeLeft` variable at the-same time resulting to your current issue.

One solution would be to use a boolean variable to detect when coroutine is already running and start is again but you mentioned that you want to create and multiple timers at the-same time. You have two options:

**1**.Move the `timeLeft` variable inside the `Countdown` function so that each function call has a `timeLeft` variable for it. Also do the-same for the `countText` variable so that a different `Text` component is used to modify the `Text` in each function call.

```
public IEnumerator Countdown()
{
    float timeLeft = 5f;
    Text countText = GameObject.Find("TextForThisCounter").GetComponent<Text>();

    while (timeLeft > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        countText.text = timeLeft.ToString("f0");
        timeLeft--;
    }
}
```

---

**2**.Move the whole coroutine function to another class then use a callback `Action` to notify you each second there is a tick in the timer and when the timer is done. I recommend this method since it is more portable and reusable. You can also implement an ID to determine which timer this is when it finish running.

Timer moved to another script:

```
public struct CountDownTimer
{
    private static int sTimerID = 0;
    private MonoBehaviour monoBehaviour;

    public int timer { get { return localTimer; } }
    private int localTimer;

    public int timerID { get { return localID; } }
    private int localID;

    public CountDownTimer(MonoBehaviour monoBehaviour)
    {
        this.monoBehaviour = monoBehaviour;
        localTimer = 0;

        //Assign timer ID
        sTimerID++;
        localID = sTimerID;
    }

    public void Start(int interval, Action<int> tickCallBack, Action<int> finshedCallBack)
    {
        localTimer = interval;
        monoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(beginCountDown(tickCallBack, finshedCallBack));
    }

    private IEnumerator beginCountDown(Action<int> tickCallBack, Action<int> finshedCallBack)
    {
        while (localTimer > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
            localTimer--;
            //Notify tickCallBack in each clock tick
            tickCallBack(localTimer);
        }

        //Notify finshedCallBack after timer is done
        finshedCallBack(localID);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

Start timer 4 times each with different ID.

```
void Start()
{
    createAndStartNewTimer();

    createAndStartNewTimer();

    createAndStartNewTimer();

    createAndStartNewTimer();
}


public void createAndStartNewTimer()
{
    //Create new Timer
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(this);

    //What to do each second time tick in the timer
    Action<int> tickCallBack = (timeLeft) =>
    {
        Debug.Log(timeLeft.ToString("f0"));
    };


    //What to do each second time tick in the timer
    Action<int> finshedCallBack = (timeriD) =>
       {
           Debug.Log("Count Down Timer Done! ID: " + timeriD);
       };

    //Start Countdown Timer from 5
    timer.Start(5, tickCallBack, finshedCallBack);
}
```

Comment: "Each time the coroutine function is called, timeLeft variable is being modified. " -- this is obvious, but the problem here is that the coroutine is called ONCE when it's only one task on the list. Why does it run twice when I add more tasks to the On click event? it shouldn't behave like this.
"but you mentioned that you want to create and multiple timers at the-same time." -- no, I didn't say that. I need it to run only once.

Comment: From your question *"When adding more than 1 task to the execution list of UI button On Click() manager, the execution of those tasks gets unpredictable behavior"* If you add ` StartCountDown()` to that `onClick` slot multiple times or more than 1, that ` StartCountDown()` function will be called that amount of time it is added. It is not a bug and should behave like that.

Comment: well, if you look carefully at the attached image, I'm not adding the same task twice, I'm adding another task which has nothing to do with my countdown script, and after that unity goes crazy and runs my coroutine twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "`yeld return null;`" at the end of the function to prevent strange behaviors